# URL Rewriting - hide part of url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an url like this one:

```
http://xxxx.com/cms/
....
http://xxxx.com/cms/about-us/concept/
http://xxxx.com/cms/something/
```

What i want is hide the cms folder of the url.

So when i type in url   `http://xxxx.com/` I should be redirected to `http://xxxx.com/cms/` but the `cms` should not be visible.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ cms/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by changing the DocumentRoot in your apache config.  In the config file just tack on "/cms" to the DocumentRoot= value and restart apache.

Comment: i don't have access to configuration files.

Comment: What do you have access to?  And what language is your site written in?

Comment: the first part of the problem can be solved with: `RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^$  /cms/index.php` 
Now, i need to find a way of hide the /cms/ in the other pages.